# How to release RAM of android from previous activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory, ram

For example, if I moved from activity1 to activity2, how can I release device memory from this first class? E.g. using ComponentsCallback2

Comment: Why not just call `finish()` in `activity1` after starting `activity2`?

Comment: Oh, It's true :)

Comment: you can kill a specific object by overriding the onDestroy method

Comment: @BayarŞahintekin No you can't.  That's not how garbage collection works

Comment: If the first Activity was destroyed, (say via finish) it will be freed for you assuming you don't have a leak or another reference to it.  If it wasn't, when you run low on memory Android will destroy it for you (sam assumptions).  If you do have a memory leak, you need to fix that and it will get properly freed.

Comment: Sometimes manual intervention may be required. I use it to prevent data leakage in my work. mine was just an idea. @GabeSechan

Comment: If you wish to know if you have memory leak issues, I highly recommend you use `LeakCanary` from Square - https://github.com/square/leakcanary  By the way, I recommend you improve your question with some information as to why you think you need to do this. Is Activity1 using too much memory and not releasing upon `onDestroy()`?

Comment: @BayarŞahintekin Sometimes that's part of an answer (like if you need to unregister things to remove references outside of the Activity).  But just overriding onDestroy without a specific reason isn't going to do anything-  especially if the Activity isn't destroyed.